# Finding Mean in Pandas, where column has np.NaN value as well

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

How do I find mean/average of a column in a Pandas DataFrame, which also includes np.NaN (NaN = Not a number) value?

Comment: Use `df['col'].mean()`, pandas by default exclude `NaN`

Comment: `df[column_name].mean()` should do the work

Comment: But if need include NaN - it means if at least one `NaN` ouput is `NaN` use `df['col'].mean(skipna=False)`